# Concurrency Spanner java stacktrace on `bq query` update column of partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created sql that does an update of all values in one column

```
UPDATE `Blackout_POC2.measurements_2020`
SET visitor.customerId_enc = enc.encrypted
FROM `Blackout_POC2.encrypted` AS enc
WHERE dateAmsterdam="2020-01-05"
AND session.visitId = enc.visitId
AND visitor.customerId = enc.plain
```

where `dateAmsterdam` is the partition key of the `measurements_2020` table, and `encrypted` is a non-partitioned table that holds `visitId`, `plain` and `encrypted` fields. The code sets all values in the `customerId_enc` column with values from the `encrypted` table.

The code works *perfectly fine* when I run it one day at a time, but when I run days in parallel, I occassionally (1% or so) get a stacktrace from my `bq query <sql>` (see below).

I thought that I could modify partitioned tables in parallel within each partition, but that seems to occassionally not be the case. Could someone point me to where this would be documented, and preferably how to avoid this?
I can probably just rerun that query again, since it is idempotent, but I would like to know why this happens.

Thanks

Bart van Deenen, data-engineer Bol.com

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'bolcom-dev-blackout-339:bqjob_r131fa5b3dfd24829_0000016faec5e5da_1': domain: "cloud.helix.ErrorDomain"
code: "QUERY_ERROR" argument: "Could not serialize access to table bolcom-dev-blackout-339:Blackout_POC2.measurements_2020 due to concurrent update"
debug_info: "[CONCURRENT_UPDATE] Table modified by concurrent UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE DML or truncation at 1579185217979. Storage set job_uuid:
03d3d5ec-2118-4e43-9fec-1eae99402c86:20200106, instance_id: ClonedTable-1579183484786, Reason: code=CONCURRENT_UPDATE message=Could not serialize
access to table bolcom-dev-blackout-339:Blackout_POC2.measurements_2020 due to concurrent update debug=Table modified by concurrent UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE
DML or truncation at 1579185217979. Storage set job_uuid: 03d3d5ec-2118-4e43-9fec-1eae99402c86:20200106, instance_id: ClonedTable-1579183484786
errorProto=domain: \"cloud.helix.ErrorDomain\"\ncode: \"QUERY_ERROR\"\nargument: \"Could not serialize access to table bolcom-dev-
blackout-339:Blackout_POC2.measurements_2020 due to concurrent update\"\ndebug_info: \"Table modified by concurrent UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE DML or
truncation at 1579185217979. Storage set job_uuid: 03d3d5ec-2118-4e43-9fec-1eae99402c86:20200106, instance_id: ClonedTable-1579183484786\"\n\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Public.concurrentUpdate(Exceptions.java:381)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Public.concurrentUpdate(Exceptions.java:373)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StorageTrackerData.verifyStorageSetUpdate(StorageTrackerData.java:224)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.validateUpdates(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:1133)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.updateStorageSets(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:1310)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.updateStorageSets(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:1293)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.MetaTableTracker.updateStorageSets(MetaTableTracker.java:2274)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.job.StorageSideEffects$1.update(StorageSideEffects.java:1123)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.job.StorageSideEffects$1.update(StorageSideEffects.java:976)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.MetaTableTracker$1.update(MetaTableTracker.java:2510)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StorageTrackerSpanner.lambda$atomicUpdate$7(StorageTrackerSpanner.java:165)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner$Factory$1.run(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:3775)\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.se
rver.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner$Factory.lambda$performJobWithCommitResult$0(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:3792)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$RetryCountingWork.run(SpannerTransactionContext.java:1002)\n\tat com.googl
e.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResultInternal(SpannerTransactionContext.java:840)\n\tat com.goo
gle.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeOptimisticWithResultInternal(SpannerTransactionContext.java:722)\n
\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.lambda$executeOptimisticWithResult$1(SpannerTransactionContex
t.java:716)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithMonitoring(SpannerTransactionContext.java:942)\n\tat co
m.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeOptimisticWithResult(SpannerTransactionContext.java:715)\n\ta
t com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner$Factory.performJobWithCommitResult(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:3792)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner$Factory.performJobWithCommitResult(AtomicStorageTrackerSpanner.java:3720)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StorageTrackerSpanner.atomicUpdate(StorageTrackerSpanner.java:159)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.MetaTableTracker.atomicUpdate(MetaTableTracker.java:2521)\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StatsRequ
estLoggingTrackers$LoggingStorageTracker.lambda$atomicUpdate$8(StatsRequestLoggingTrackers.java:494)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StatsRequestLoggingTrackers$StatsRecorder.record(StatsRequestLoggingTrackers.java:181)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StatsRequestLoggingTrackers$StatsRecorder.record(StatsRequestLoggingTrackers.java:158)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StatsRequestLoggingTrackers$StatsRecorder.access$500(StatsRequestLoggingTrackers.java:123)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.StatsRequestLoggingTrackers$LoggingStorageTracker.atomicUpdate(StatsRequestLoggingTrackers.java:493)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.job.StorageSideEffects.apply(StorageSideEffects.java:1238)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.MergeStorageImpl.commitChanges(MergeStorageImpl.java:936)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.MergeStorageImpl.merge(MergeStorageImpl.java:729)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.StorageStubby.mergeStorage(StorageStubby.java:937)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.proto2.Storage$ServiceParameters$21.handleBlockingRequest(Storage.java:2100)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.helix.proto2.Storage$ServiceParameters$21.handleBlockingRequest(Storage.java:2098)\n\tat
com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcBlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(RpcBlockingApplicationHandler.java:28)\n\tat
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery DML operations doesn't have support for [multi-statement transactions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations); nevertheless, you can execute some concurrent statements:

```
UPDATE and INSERT
DELETE and INSERT
INSERT and INSERT
```

For example, you execute two UPDATES statements simultaneously against the table then only one of them will succeed.

Keeping this in mind, due you can execute concurrently UPDATE and INSERT statements, another possible cause is if you are executing multiple UPDATE statements simultaneously.

You could try using the Scripting feature to [manage the execution flow](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) to prevent DML concurrency.